# Ember.js Nested folder like route (contain slash)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building an app with file manager like functionality with Ember.js. I'd like the URL for nested folder in the form of **".../#/files/Nested/Inside/"** and it works fine with `linkTo`; however if I refresh (or go to the URL directly) I have the error message "No route match the URL '/files/Nested/Inside'". Is there any way to make Ember.js works in situation like this? Thanks.

Here is my current route setup:

```
FM.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('folders', { path: '/files' })
  this.resource('folder', { path: '/files/:path' })
})

FM.FoldersRoute = EM.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return FM.Folder.find('/')
  }
})

FM.FolderRoute = EM.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return ns.Folder.find(params.path)
  },
  serialize: function(folder) {
    return { path: folder.get('path') }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, interesting question. It *should* be possible but I've not tried it myself or seen any examples of this in the wild.

Under the hood, ember uses the tildeio [router](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js) and [route-recognizer](https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer) to resolve routes. The route's readme explains how to [define more elaborate routes](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js#route-recognizer) like:

```
router.map(function(match) {
  // this will match anything, followed by a slash,
  // followed by a dynamic segment (one or more non-
  // slash characters)
  match("/*page/:location").to("showPage");
});
```

So to get nested folders working, you might be able to do something like this:

```
FM.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('folders', { path: '/files' })
  this.resource('folder', { path: '/files/*path' })
})
```

Hope this helps.