# Ember.js dynamic route segment with a hash sign with locationType: "hash"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building an Ember application that takes path to other document as a route dynamic segment parameter. The document is further displayed in iframe inside my app. I'm using a `locationType: hash` option in environment and a wildcard route as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053050/1367361

The route is defined as:

```
this.route('display', {path: '*document_path'});
```

After entering URL like this:

```
http://localhost/#/display/some/document.html
```

The `route:display` invokes `model` method with parameter:

```
{ document_path: "some/document.html" }
```

I want to be able to pass `#` sign in the `document_path`, but entering URL like this:

```
http://localhost/#/display/some/document.html#some-paragraph
```

cuts everything after the `#` sign and passes:

```
{ document_path: "some/document.html" }
```

into the `model`.

**I know that it works if I change `locationType` to `history`. But at the moment for some reason I want to use `hash` `locationType`.**

It is possible to pass the `#` as a dynamic segment when using `locationType: hash`?

Comment: You could encode it, but I don't think that's what you're after?

Comment: Yes, I can encode/decode it to other char, but I'm curious if using raw ``#`` is possible and my goal is to see it in URL. Anyway, if there is no other way, I will do that.